# Where can i find dot db Files in linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux, raspberry-pi, mariadb

I'm using a Rasberry pi system in that i use Mysql(Maria DB) as Database i just wanted to copy the .db files from the system and i'm unable to find the location where it all have been stored.

Any solutions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To find the database files, look for the `datadir` line in /etc/my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

It's usually /var/lib/mysql even on mariadb.

However mysql and mariadb don't - as far as I know - store data in .db files. What system are you hoping to copy the data over to? You've tagged this Java: are you trying to load the data into H2 or similar?

If you want to copy the database between systems then I'd recommend backing-up/exporting the data with [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) and reimporting it into a new MySQL/MariaDB instance.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information i just wanted to copy the .db files directly to a pendrive i found /var/lib/mysql but there is folders in the name of databases i have created and inside that i have .ibd and .frm files in the name of tables i just want .db where can i get it or copying and placing the db folder in another system  /var/lib/mysql will it create the same db in that system too?

Comment: @s.suryaPrakash mysql does not have .db files, that's sqlite. You cannot simply move the mysql data files to another host and expect it to work.